# JavaFx, add tooltip for tableview that shows cell contents

Tags: javafx, tooltip, tableview

I have a tableview in JavaFX app, the table displays dynamic contents that have been retrieved from an external source.

The app works fine, but sometimes the cell content (text only) is very long and only part of it appears. I would like to add a tooltip that simply displays the content of each cell, so the user doesn't have to resize the column width to set the whole text.

Thanks

Comment: So, this is the only way (using cell factory)?

Comment: Yes, the only way (without significant hacks) you can access the cell is via the cell factory.